# Take ScreenShot of Visible screen Android

Tags: android, kotlin, screenshot, android-workmanager

I want to take screen shot of any visible screen from background. I don't want to be dependent on activity context. Whatever screen I open in my device like browser or any social app I just want to take screenshot of that.

I tried different approaches but it is depended on activity and we can only take screenshot of current App.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Use the media projection APIs, available on Android 5.0+.

Comment: @CommonsWare i think i can achieve my goal with this API. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Works only for rooted diveces

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor();
```