how to take screenshot from workamanager worker in android studio java?
I want to take screenshot of my phone screen from background by android workmanager. is there a way to do it without rooting my phone?
I have tried to do it by Bitmap creator but it asking for a view. my workmanager worker does not have a view.

Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67146537/take-screenshot-of-visible-screen-android help you?
